# Using -like to find strings with Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

In Powershell, I need to find multiple errors within a text file and the closest desired word between them. Each error is contained in an array. In the past, I would use the code:

```
#creating null array
$results = @("")
#creating index for array
for ($i = 0; $i -lt ($errors.length - 1); $i++)
{
    $results += $false
}
#selecting string
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $errors.length; $i++)
{
     $k = $errors[$i]
     $rg = [regex]"WORD.*?$k.*?WORD"
     $results[$i] = $content | Select-String -Pattern $rg -AllMatches | Foreach-Object {($_.Matches |
                    ForEach-Object {$_.value})}
}
```

`$errors` is the array of errors, `$content` is the content of the text file, and each item in `$results` holds the string from desired word to error to desired word.

Using `$results[$i] = $content | Select-String -Pattern $rg -AllMatches | Foreach-Object {($_.Matches | ForEach-Object {$_.value})}` does not work because my errors contain wild cards like asterisks.

I know that in order for me to do such characters, I need to use `-like`

I have tried using `$results[$i] = $content -like $k` instead, but that only returns a null value.

Comment: You can escape wildcards and other regex special characters --> `$k = [regex]::Escape($errors[$i])`

Comment: Initialize Array: [bool[]]$results = @( (,$false) * $errors.length )

Comment: You can also escape PowerShell wildcards for operators that accept standard wildcards --> `[WildcardPattern]::Escape($errors[$i])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $errors.length; $i++)
{
     $k = [regex]::Escape($errors[$i])
     $rg = [regex]"(?s)WORD.*?$k.*?WORD"
     $results[$i] = $content | Select-String -Pattern $rg -AllMatches |
         Foreach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
}
```

I do not know what is inside of `$errors`, `$results`, or `$content`. For what you want to work as intended while `$content` spans multiple lines, then `$content` will need to be a single string before being piped into `Select-String`. Otherwise, your regex will only match against one line at a time.

Since you may want `.*?` to match multiple lines, you should use the `(?s)` mode so that `.` can match new line characters.

If `$errors` contains characters that have special meaning in regex, you will need to backslash escape them. An easy way to do that is to call the Regex .NET class method `Escape()`.

Comment: That gives me from the very first desired word to the very last desired word in the text file. Each error is in their own section and they are divided up by these desired words.  I need each section to be in their own array item, so I can go on from there.  Also, I can't give you the contents as it contains PHI. Thanks.

Comment: You should provide sample data from your file. You can delete out sensitive information.

Comment: ~HL~firstname~error1~city~state~HL~business~notAnError~employeeID~HL~firstname~lastname~error2~supervisorID~HL~division~error1~customerID~HL

Above text is obtained in $content where ~HL are the desired words and error1 and error2 are the errors listed out in $errors. ~notAnError~ is not listed in $error, and therefore should be ignored.